# multiple parameters in url not working Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-routing

I'm using `Angular 6` and have configured my routes like

```
export const AuthLayoutRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'reset-password/:password_hash/:user_id_hash', component: ResetPasswordComponent},
];
```

But when I visit the url

```
https://example.com/reset-password/8d042fcb-8892/c81e728d9d4c2f
```

It give **404** error.

Visiting only `https://example.com/reset-password` is loading the component.

Comment: Please show entire routing module

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should define multiple routes using the same component, with and without the last parameter, as seen below:

```
      export const AuthLayoutRoutes: Routes = [
      { path: 'reset-password/:password_hash/:user_id_hash', component: ResetPasswordComponent},
      { path: 'reset-password/:password_hash', component: ResetPasswordComponent},
    ];
```

I hope it helps ;)

Answer (score -2):

I just created simple app which will cover your issue,
you can check it

[here on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4hf1rf)

hope it help.